# Windows Keyboard Repeating/Skipping Issue returns after every OS update

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse

One day, I booted up my PC and noticed my keyboard was typing incorrectly. Sometimes it will 'time out' for a second or two, ignoring any key input. Sometimes, it will freeze on a key I just pressed, repeating the key infinitely until it recognizes I've pressed another key.

### Example

I will type the phrase `let's go to the beach` on the keyboard now:

`ltssssss     gooooooooooooooooooo te bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbch`

### What I've tried

1. Changing Repeat Delay settings
2. Going to Device Manager, Uninstalling all keyboard/usb drivers; restarting. Used to work; doesn't anymore.
3. Getting a full driver update from CCleaner
4. Getting rid of all 3rd-party keyboard software + registry entries. (used to use a Razer keyboard)

I've ruled out hardware issues because I bought a new keyboard a while back and had the same problem... Even text entry in the On-Screen Keyboard misses or repeats sometimes; though its rare.

I've been searching using the keyboard as the issue, but when the problem occurs, my mouse and mic also give me problems...

I've had this issue for a few years, but after an update last night my usual tricks don't work. I have no idea what to do now.

I have verified that this issue does **not** happen when I boot into Safe Mode.

### Specs

Windows 10 Pro 21H1 19043.1237 x64

Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1620 0 @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz

Comment: Open Windows in Safe Mode with nothing at all loaded and check the Keyboard operation in Safe Mode.

Comment: Uninstalling USB drivers for your keyboard and mouse is an almost guaranteed way of causing more harm to your system than good, and I have never seen anyone with this problem, actually solve a keyboard/mouse problem by uninstalling the default USB device drivers for those devices.  I would agree, boot into Safe Mode, and verify the problem exists there and [edit] your question.

Comment: @Ashton French: Does you keyboard connected directly to the computer or perhaps you are using an **_KVM Switch_**, an extension cord?

Comment: @John apologies for the delay, the issue just popped up for the first time in a month. The issue does not show when I boot up in Safe Mode.